# sql telling how many days have passed(datediff)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, datediff

I'm working on a project where I want to display data after 3 days have passed.

What I'm having an issue with is getting the current date dynamically in php/sql. I'm aware of how to get the current date in php, but I dont know how to compare that value to the date that I have in the sql database.

Comment: The docs would be a good place to start... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html   mysql has a zillion useful date/time functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that directly in SQL

```
select * from your_table
where date_column <= curdate() - interval 3 day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interval select to limit the records to within 3 days if the column you're checking istimestamp, date, or datetime.

```
select * from tablename where timestamp_column >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DATEDIFF** function to check for days.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), datecol) >= 3;
```